# Tell me, when script has finished

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, terminal

Some years ago I had a small script[1] called beep-forever which ringed the terminal bell for ever.

Use case: I want to know if a script has finished:

```
do-foo-which-lasts-ten-to-thirty-minutes.sh; beep-forever.sh
```

In my environment (several people in one room) I don't want to use this.

How could I get this information?

I am connected to remote linux servers via ssh. AFAIK there is no connection to the desktop environment of my ubuntu PC. And sending mail does not work on most remote servers.

[1] http://www.thomas-guettler.de/scripts/beep-forever.sh.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible option:

Install ImageMagik on the linux server. SSH into the server from your PC ensuring [X Forwarding](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12755/how-to-forward-x-over-ssh-from-ubuntu-machine) is enabled. Make sure you enable [XAUTH](http://www.x.org/archive/X11R6.8.1/doc/xauth.1.html) on your Ubuntu PC, and do something like:

dofoo.sh && display image.png

This would pop an image up on your local desktop when dofoo.sh completes. Not quite a beep, but it will alert you with a popup image locally.

Comment: I like this solution